# Merge two mysql rows into one using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel, response

I have a table named messages that has the structure as follow:

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | message | sent_at
```

I have made a system that whenever a user selects a particular user the messages that are sent by or received by him are shown in the page in proper manner. For that I have the following code that does the thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMessages(elem){
    let id = $(elem).attr('id');
    let myId = "<?php echo \Session::get('user_id'); ?>";
    console.log(id, myId);
    $.get("/get-messages",
{
    id_no_1: id,
    id_no_2: myId
}, function(data){
    alert(data)
});
}
```

Here, I get the user_id of the associated user and my own user and perform an AJAX request to the route and the route has:

```
Route::get('/get-messages', 'PagesController@getMessages');
```

And my major function looks like this:

```
public function getMessages(){
    $id_no_1 = request('id_no_1');
    $id_no_2 = request('id_no_2');
    $messagesSendByOneToTwo = DB::table('messages')
            ->where('sender_id', $id_no_1)
            ->where('receiver_id', $id_no_2)
            ->get();
    // $messagesSendByOneToTwo = json_encode($messagesSendByOneToTwo);

    $messagesSendByTwoToOne = DB::table('messages')
            ->where('sender_id', $id_no_2)
            ->where('receiver_id', $id_no_1)
            ->get();
    // $messagesSendByOneToTwo = json_encode($messagesSendByTwoToOne);

    $allMessages = array_merge($messagesSendByOneToTwo, $messagesSendByTwoToOne);

    $allMessages = json_encode($allMessages);

    echo $allMessages;


}
```

There I have two variables and I want to merge the two variable into a single variable. I tried `array_merge();` which I knew wouldn't work because the variables aren't arrays. To this problem, I have the following possible solutions:

- Merge the two variables into one and perform things with it. (But, I don't know how to do that.
- Send two variables as the response to the JavaScript function handling the response (which I have never heard of).
- Returning to a new view with the variables (which doesn't seem to be a good idea)
  So, what should I do to solve this problem?
  The best way would be to merge the variables into a new one so what should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for you to do two queries to begin with:

```
public function getMessages(){
    $id_no_1 = request('id_no_1');
    $id_no_2 = request('id_no_2');
    $messagesSent = DB::table('messages')
        ->whereIn('sender_id', [ $id_no_1, $id_no_2 ])
        ->whereIn('receiver_id', [ $id_no_1, $id_no_2 ])
        ->get();


    return response()->json($messagesSent); //This is better than echoing json   
}
```

Comment: It prints out (or alerts out) `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. What might be the problem @apokryfos?

Comment: The response should be an array of objects. Try doing a `console.log(data)` and check the console to see how the result actually looks like

Answer (score -1):

If you want an array you can try following code to get array instead of collection.

```
messagesSendByOneToTwo = DB::table('messages')
            ->where('sender_id', $id_no_1)
            ->where('receiver_id', $id_no_2)
            ->get()->toArray();
```